# Why am I getting UI bugs with Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: gui, ubuntu-gnome

I've been loving using Ubuntu. But after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 I am getting weird UI glitches like this and display issues when changing system resolution. Can someone help me with this issue?

[image: Weird buttons on quick settings panel]

Comment: Confirm you are using the Yaru icon theme. You may need to reinstall it. In your screenshot, the ">" and headphone icons are larger than they should be. The other icons are the correct sizes. Either you are using a derivative Yaru theme, or your icon theme is corrupted in some way.